# Different handling of reboot at "identical" Debian 8 servers

Tags: ssh, debian, reboot

We have several servers, all running Debian 8 (up-to-date) and configured exactly the same by ansible. These servers run on different hardware / vps.

However, there is a difference between them in how they react on a reboot command (in this example two servers, using the same vm type hosted by the same service provider).

When logging in at server 1 (via ssh) and reboot, the connection is broken and i am back in the local client terminal. That's okay.

```
$ sudo reboot
Connection to my.server1.com closed by remote host.
Connection to my.server1.com closed.
```

However, server 2 "hangs" after reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
<terminal freezes>
```

What can be a possible cause of this different behavior? What do i need to check / change?